# Linux Traffic Control (tc) not working without reboot

Tags: rhel, kernel, kernel-modules

When trying to run

```
   tc qdisc add dev $INTERFACE root handle 1: prio priomap 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2
   tc qdisc add dev $INTERFACE parent 1:1 handle 10: netem loss "${LOSS}"%
```

I get the error of

`Specified qdisc not found`

`yum -y install kernel-modules-extra` works as a fix, but requires a reboot.

In my case, a reboot is not an option

Is there a way around a reboot to get `qdisk` working?

RHEL 8.6

Answer (score 0):

Found a way, depending on the RHEL release, but works for my uses.

```
yumdownloader --resolve kernel-modules-extra
rpm2cpio kernel-modules-extra-*.rpm | cpio -idmv
mv lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/sched/sch_netem.ko.xz /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/sched/
xz -d /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/sched/sch_netem.ko.xz
insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/net/sched/sch_netem.ko
```